# how to copy an index of a 2 dimensional array to another index java android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to copy an index of a 2 dimensional array to another index of the same array.

MY CODE:

```
for (int f=0; f<(wp[donsay-1].length); f++) {
  wp[donsay][f] = wp[donsay - 1][f];
}
```

With this code I am desperatly trying to copy the previous index to the next index. `donsay=1` and the `wp[0][n]...` has been filled manually.

This gives the following error:

```
Shutting down VM
12-27 04:37:04.610 26200-26200/chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                              Process: chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray, PID: 26200
                                                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray/chessactivesekizsatirvetekliarray.com.sekizsatirvetekliarray.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

Any help will be much aprreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means you're trying to access an index of the array that doesn't exist. Check that you can access things such as `wp[donsay-1]`, `wp[donsay][f]` and `wp[donsay - 1][f]` by stepping through your code in debug mode.

I'm also not sure how the for loop is meant to work for a 2d array, since you essentially need a for loop within a for loop to go over the whole array

Comment: What if I had an ArrayList and tried to copy the previous index to the next. Any help on that... because it is clear that this won't do with arrays...

Comment: If `donsay` is 1 like you said then why is there no issue with the following code: `Integer[][] wp = new Integer[100][100];
    int donsay = 1;

    for (int f=0; f<(wp[donsay-1].length); f++) {
      wp[donsay][f] = wp[donsay - 1][f];
    }`
Also why not use `System.arraycopy(wp[donsay - 1], 0, wp[donsay], 0, wp[donsay - 1].length);` instead of a manual array copy?